# Php - Customize the title and picture of the file downloaded

Tags: php

I have a simple question, Currently im using the function `header("Content-Diposition....")` to download a file. My question is :

Is it possible to customize the name and the picture of the download ?

I have currently this :

[image]

Thanks in advance for your help.

Comment: You can define the name of the downloaded file. Show us your code and we can help you from there.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can set name by `Content-Disposition: attachment; filename=FILENAME`. File icon depends on the file type, so try to use proper file extension and `Content-Type` in http header.